# What are the caveats of using MongoDB for message passing?

Tags: mongodb, message-queue, message-passing

MongoDB can be used for real-time message passing by using a tailable cursor to tail a capped collection.

What are the caveats of using MongoDB for this purpose? One obvious issue would be that there are no in-memory collections, so messages may be written to disk when there's no need for persistence.

Answer (score 1):

One caveat is that if you had a replica set, only one Mongo machine can accept writes. That would limit how many writes you could do for the queue.

The other obvious caveat is that with a capped collection you would obviously have to read/consume the messages before they started to drop out of the collection. If the consumer ever went down - and you didn't catch it fast enough - you'd lose messages.

I got confused with your last sentence. =( I'm sure you know Mongo does its best to keep everything in RAM. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/ They make no mention that capped collections would not be in RAM (unless your working set is too big for RAM).